# Finding the n-th prime number that is palindrome in base K

Tags: c, algorithm, palindrome

I recently asked a question about finding whether a number is palindrome in base K or not and I get my answer.
[My Recent Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973157/checking-if-a-number-is-palindrome-in-arbitrary-base-k-without-array?noredirect=1#comment92853725_52973157)

Now I have a more complicated question, We will get two numbers n and k, and we must find the n-th prime number that is palindrome in base K.

For example if we get 8 and 10, we have 2 3 5 7 11 101 131 151 which are palindrome and prime and so the answer is 151. Another example is 4 2 we have 3 5 7 17 respectively 11 101 111 10001 in base 2 which are prime and palindrome in base so the answer is 17.

n and k are given such that the answer is at most, 1E7.

I submit my program in a judge system and It gave wrong answer in some cases and also Time Limit error in one case. I don't know which part of my algorithm is wrong and what part of it is not optimised.

Note that I am not allowed to use array,vector and strings and also I cannot use libraries more than stdio.h and math.h. It is my program, Can anyone find any problems in it: (I defined intPow because the pow function in math, gives a float and sometime it causes problems)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int primeCheck ( int n);
int palindrome ( int n,int base);
int digitCountBase (int n , int base);
int intPow (int a , int b);
int main()
{
    int n;
    int base;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&base);
    int counter = 0;
    int i =2;
    int firstRound =1;
    while (counter!=n)
    {

        if (primeCheck(i))
        {
            if (palindrome (i,base))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter ==n)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (firstRound)
        {
            i++;
            firstRound=0;
        }
        else{i+=2;}

    }
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
int primeCheck ( int n)
{
    if (n<2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n==4)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n<=5)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n%2 ==0 || n%3 ==0 || n% 5 ==0)
    {

        return 0;
    }
     int i =5;
     int limit = sqrt(n)+2;
    for (int i =5;i<=limit;i+=6)
    {
        if (n%i==0||n%(i+2)==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int palindrome ( int n,int base)
{
    int isTrue = 1;
    int digitCount = digitCountBase(n,base);

    int power = intPow(base,digitCount-1);
    while (n>0&& digitCount >0)
    {

        if (n%base != (n/power)&&digitCount!=1)
        {
            isTrue =0;
            return 0;

        }
        n = n- power;
        n=n/base;
        power = power /base;
        power = power /base;
        digitCount=digitCount-2;
    }

    return isTrue;

}
int digitCountBase (int n , int base)
{
    int digits=0;
    while (n)
    {
        digits++;
        n = n / base;
    }
return digits;

}

int intPow (int a , int b)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<=b;i++)
    {
        result = result * a;
    }
    return result;


}
```

Comment: The problem with these questions that say "I submitted my code to a judge system and it said the answers were wrong" is that, we don't know what the test case is, what the expected output was, or what the actual output was. All of those are normally required when putting up a "why isn't my code working?" question. I would ask the OP to run some tests and try to spot some incorrect answers.

Comment: The programming challenges in online judges want you to find an efficient algorithm. Looping over all numbers and then checking both palindromity and primality isn't very efficient. Try to find a way to generate palindromes and then check for primality (or vice versa). Also, these questions usually tell you the range of possible inputs. Yu could share them here, so that we can see whether you run into numerical overflow.

Comment: @M Oehm I don't know the test cases. It is only known that base is from 2 to 20. Nothing is known except that the final answer will not exceed 1E7. I think the question has 4 second time limit. my whole primecheck from 0 to 1E7 is done in 1.4 seconds in my PC.

Comment: @user3386109 I said I cannot use array at the Note before the Code. It would be much simpler if array was allowed. The Judge will give runtime error if I use of array or strings or vectors because the question purpose is mostly algorithm.

Comment: The other thing about programming competitions is that they are intended to measure *your* programming abilities, not ours. And programming is not just typing into a text editor; it includes more important skills including algorithmic design and debugging. You will learn quite a lot more by sitting back and thinking about your problem than by searching the internet for copyable solutions or begging for help on online forums. Even if you fail to find the answer, the practice at analytic thinking will help make you a better programmer.

Comment: @rici It is not from a competition. It is a question of a course in a persian language hackerrank-like- site.

Comment: primeCheck works fine, counts correct number of primes from 1 to 10^7

Comment: @titansarus: Then my point about learning stands but here's a hint: how many base-k palindromes are there which are less than k to the power of 2d? Answer: 2k^d, because every d-digit number generates two unique palindromes , one of even length and one of odd length. (I'll leave you to extend that observation to odd-length ranges). But the count isn't important (although it implies that there are only a few thousand palindromes less than 1E7); what's important is how that thought leads you to enumerating them in order.

Comment: hint: palindrome(56, 3) gives wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: change palindrome to

```
int palindrome ( int n,int base)
    {
        int isTrue = 1;
        int digitCount = digitCountBase(n,base);
        int power = intPow(base,digitCount-1);

        int original = n;
        while (n>0&& digitCount >0)
        {

            if (n%base != (original/power) % base &&digitCount!=1)
            {
                isTrue =0;
                return 0;

            }
            n=n/base;
            power = power /base;
            digitCount=digitCount-2;
        }

        return isTrue;

    }
```

How did I find the error:

- You are doing only 2 things, primality testing and palindrome testing, so makes sense to check if these are working fine.
- Primality testing is easy, count primes from 1 to 10^7 and compare to known values on google. In this case, this works
- To test palindrome, pick a working solution from the internet (even if you can´t submit their solution that uses arrays/strings, you can test with them!). Then iterate from 1 to 10^7 in a certain base and check that both functions return the same.
- Testing with base 3, quickly saw that 56 was not giving same output. And the incorrect one was yours.
- Then its a matter of fixing your function, which you now know which one is the problem and even have an example of where its not working

Comment: The issue was with something like 101111. My method was ignoring the 0 but your method works fine. Thanks you very much.